# Прокрутка страницы до определенной позиции

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день.

Я гуглил-гуглил, так ничего внятного и не нашел - либо слишком замороченные методы, либо так невнятно написано, что понять, как сделать, не получается.

Задача такова: при нажатии на кнопку страница прокручивается до определенного значения!
Просьба: подскажите максимально простой метод, посоветуйте, потому что, повторяю, я нашел достаточно, но там для такой пустяковой задачки такие навороченные решения.

Comment: [Пример][1] [Описание][2]


  [1]: http://demos.dconnell.co.uk/scrollToElement/
  [2]: http://www.jqueryrain.com/?fg_PjSSQ

Comment: Зачем далеко ходить, ответы есть и тут: [ответ 1][1] и [ответ 2][2]


[1]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/392012#392019
[2]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/379099#379110

Comment: Либо все, кто тут ответил - избранные самими Гуглом, либо кому-то было лень зайти в гугл! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дааа уж, гугл в растерянности...

Например так:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ЗНАЧЕНИЕ //$("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```